# Restriction resources kubernetes cluster for web-service

Tags: go, kubernetes

I have golang web service in kubernetes cluster. Kubernetes let me set limits for resource usage, but response time from my service increased immediately after I set any limits. As I see in trace, my application waiting for CPU time despite I set it more than enough. Came someone across with this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you share some numbres? how many CPU do you have in total and what is the limits you have set?

Comment: Hi, Try to put the pod in guaranty QoS by having same amount of CPU and RAM in request and limit fields. If its in different QoS class , different behavior can occure during resources contentions time,

Comment: You can use `kubectl top pod <pod_name>` and check how much resources have been used by it and if it's close to your limit, amp up the limit.